# Predis, PHP - Iterating through keys using glob not working

Tags: php, predis

So I have the following code:

```
use Predis\Collection\Iterator;

static function GetRecords($email) {
    //this gets the redis client in read/write mode
    $redis = GetRedisClient(true);

    $glob = "users:{$email}*";

    $i = 0;


    foreach(new Iterator\Keyspace($redis, $glob) as $key) {
        echo "$key<br>";
    }
}
```

but for some reason it's not working. The script just hangs forever as if it's in an infinite loop and nothing happens. When I do a:

```
print_r(new Iterator\Keyspace($redis, $glob));
```

it prints out an object instead of an array of keys. I'm not sure what to do to iterate through the keys. I have tried the glob from the command line and it works just fine, it's PHP that's giving me trouble.

edit: here is the output for the print_r:

```
Predis\Collection\Iterator\Keyspace Object
(
[client:protected] => Predis\Client Object
    (
        [connection:protected] => Predis\Connection\StreamConnection Object
            (
                [resource:Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection:private] => Resource id #34
                [cachedId:Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection:private] => 
                [parameters:protected] => Predis\Connection\Parameters Object
                    (
                        [parameters:Predis\Connection\Parameters:private] => Array
                            (
                                [host] => 127.0.0.1
                                [port] => 6383
                                [scheme] => tcp
                                [timeout] => 5
                            )

                    )

                [initCommands:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [options:protected] => Predis\Configuration\Options Object
            (
                [input:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [options:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [connections] => Predis\Connection\Factory Object
                            (
                                [schemes:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [tcp] => Predis\Connection\StreamConnection
                                        [unix] => Predis\Connection\StreamConnection
                                        [redis] => Predis\Connection\StreamConnection
                                        [http] => Predis\Connection\WebdisConnection
                                    )

                            )

                        [profile] => Predis\Profile\RedisVersion300 Object
                            (
                                [commands:Predis\Profile\RedisProfile:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [EXISTS] => Predis\Command\KeyExists
                                        [DEL] => Predis\Command\KeyDelete
                                        [TYPE] => Predis\Command\KeyType
                                        [KEYS] => Predis\Command\KeyKeys
                                        [RANDOMKEY] => Predis\Command\KeyRandom
                                        [RENAME] => Predis\Command\KeyRename
                                        [RENAMENX] => Predis\Command\KeyRenamePreserve
                                        [EXPIRE] => Predis\Command\KeyExpire
                                        [EXPIREAT] => Predis\Command\KeyExpireAt
                                        [TTL] => Predis\Command\KeyTimeToLive
                                        [MOVE] => Predis\Command\KeyMove
                                        [SORT] => Predis\Command\KeySort
                                        [DUMP] => Predis\Command\KeyDump
                                        [RESTORE] => Predis\Command\KeyRestore
                                        [SET] => Predis\Command\StringSet
                                        [SETNX] => Predis\Command\StringSetPreserve
                                        [MSET] => Predis\Command\StringSetMultiple
                                        [MSETNX] => Predis\Command\StringSetMultiplePreserve
                                        [GET] => Predis\Command\StringGet
                                        [MGET] => Predis\Command\StringGetMultiple
                                        [GETSET] => Predis\Command\StringGetSet
                                        [INCR] => Predis\Command\StringIncrement
                                        [INCRBY] => Predis\Command\StringIncrementBy
                                        [DECR] => Predis\Command\StringDecrement
                                        [DECRBY] => Predis\Command\StringDecrementBy
                                        [RPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPushTail
                                        [LPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPushHead
                                        [LLEN] => Predis\Command\ListLength
                                        [LRANGE] => Predis\Command\ListRange
                                        [LTRIM] => Predis\Command\ListTrim
                                        [LINDEX] => Predis\Command\ListIndex
                                        [LSET] => Predis\Command\ListSet
                                        [LREM] => Predis\Command\ListRemove
                                        [LPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopFirst
                                        [RPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopLast
                                        [RPOPLPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastPushHead
                                        [SADD] => Predis\Command\SetAdd
                                        [SREM] => Predis\Command\SetRemove
                                        [SPOP] => Predis\Command\SetPop
                                        [SMOVE] => Predis\Command\SetMove
                                        [SCARD] => Predis\Command\SetCardinality
                                        [SISMEMBER] => Predis\Command\SetIsMember
                                        [SINTER] => Predis\Command\SetIntersection
                                        [SINTERSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetIntersectionStore
                                        [SUNION] => Predis\Command\SetUnion
                                        [SUNIONSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetUnionStore
                                        [SDIFF] => Predis\Command\SetDifference
                                        [SDIFFSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetDifferenceStore
                                        [SMEMBERS] => Predis\Command\SetMembers
                                        [SRANDMEMBER] => Predis\Command\SetRandomMember
                                        [ZADD] => Predis\Command\ZSetAdd
                                        [ZINCRBY] => Predis\Command\ZSetIncrementBy
                                        [ZREM] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemove
                                        [ZRANGE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRange
                                        [ZREVRANGE] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRange
                                        [ZRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRangeByScore
                                        [ZCARD] => Predis\Command\ZSetCardinality
                                        [ZSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetScore
                                        [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByScore
                                        [PING] => Predis\Command\ConnectionPing
                                        [AUTH] => Predis\Command\ConnectionAuth
                                        [SELECT] => Predis\Command\ConnectionSelect
                                        [ECHO] => Predis\Command\ConnectionEcho
                                        [QUIT] => Predis\Command\ConnectionQuit
                                        [INFO] => Predis\Command\ServerInfoV26x
                                        [SLAVEOF] => Predis\Command\ServerSlaveOf
                                        [MONITOR] => Predis\Command\ServerMonitor
                                        [DBSIZE] => Predis\Command\ServerDatabaseSize
                                        [FLUSHDB] => Predis\Command\ServerFlushDatabase
                                        [FLUSHALL] => Predis\Command\ServerFlushAll
                                        [SAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerSave
                                        [BGSAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerBackgroundSave
                                        [LASTSAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerLastSave
                                        [SHUTDOWN] => Predis\Command\ServerShutdown
                                        [BGREWRITEAOF] => Predis\Command\ServerBackgroundRewriteAOF
                                        [SETEX] => Predis\Command\StringSetExpire
                                        [APPEND] => Predis\Command\StringAppend
                                        [SUBSTR] => Predis\Command\StringSubstr
                                        [BLPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopFirstBlocking
                                        [BRPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastBlocking
                                        [ZUNIONSTORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetUnionStore
                                        [ZINTERSTORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetIntersectionStore
                                        [ZCOUNT] => Predis\Command\ZSetCount
                                        [ZRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetRank
                                        [ZREVRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRank
                                        [ZREMRANGEBYRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByRank
                                        [HSET] => Predis\Command\HashSet
                                        [HSETNX] => Predis\Command\HashSetPreserve
                                        [HMSET] => Predis\Command\HashSetMultiple
                                        [HINCRBY] => Predis\Command\HashIncrementBy
                                        [HGET] => Predis\Command\HashGet
                                        [HMGET] => Predis\Command\HashGetMultiple
                                        [HDEL] => Predis\Command\HashDelete
                                        [HEXISTS] => Predis\Command\HashExists
                                        [HLEN] => Predis\Command\HashLength
                                        [HKEYS] => Predis\Command\HashKeys
                                        [HVALS] => Predis\Command\HashValues
                                        [HGETALL] => Predis\Command\HashGetAll
                                        [MULTI] => Predis\Command\TransactionMulti
                                        [EXEC] => Predis\Command\TransactionExec
                                        [DISCARD] => Predis\Command\TransactionDiscard
                                        [SUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubSubscribe
                                        [UNSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubUnsubscribe
                                        [PSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubSubscribeByPattern
                                        [PUNSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubUnsubscribeByPattern
                                        [PUBLISH] => Predis\Command\PubSubPublish
                                        [CONFIG] => Predis\Command\ServerConfig
                                        [PERSIST] => Predis\Command\KeyPersist
                                        [STRLEN] => Predis\Command\StringStrlen
                                        [SETRANGE] => Predis\Command\StringSetRange
                                        [GETRANGE] => Predis\Command\StringGetRange
                                        [SETBIT] => Predis\Command\StringSetBit
                                        [GETBIT] => Predis\Command\StringGetBit
                                        [RPUSHX] => Predis\Command\ListPushTailX
                                        [LPUSHX] => Predis\Command\ListPushHeadX
                                        [LINSERT] => Predis\Command\ListInsert
                                        [BRPOPLPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastPushHeadBlocking
                                        [ZREVRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRangeByScore
                                        [WATCH] => Predis\Command\TransactionWatch
                                        [UNWATCH] => Predis\Command\TransactionUnwatch
                                        [OBJECT] => Predis\Command\ServerObject
                                        [SLOWLOG] => Predis\Command\ServerSlowlog
                                        [CLIENT] => Predis\Command\ServerClient
                                        [PTTL] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseTimeToLive
                                        [PEXPIRE] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseExpire
                                        [PEXPIREAT] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseExpireAt
                                        [MIGRATE] => Predis\Command\KeyMigrate
                                        [PSETEX] => Predis\Command\StringPreciseSetExpire
                                        [INCRBYFLOAT] => Predis\Command\StringIncrementByFloat
                                        [BITOP] => Predis\Command\StringBitOp
                                        [BITCOUNT] => Predis\Command\StringBitCount
                                        [HINCRBYFLOAT] => Predis\Command\HashIncrementByFloat
                                        [EVAL] => Predis\Command\ServerEval
                                        [EVALSHA] => Predis\Command\ServerEvalSHA
                                        [SCRIPT] => Predis\Command\ServerScript
                                        [TIME] => Predis\Command\ServerTime
                                        [SENTINEL] => Predis\Command\ServerSentinel
                                        [SCAN] => Predis\Command\KeyScan
                                        [BITPOS] => Predis\Command\StringBitPos
                                        [SSCAN] => Predis\Command\SetScan
                                        [ZSCAN] => Predis\Command\ZSetScan
                                        [ZLEXCOUNT] => Predis\Command\ZSetLexCount
                                        [ZRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetRangeByLex
                                        [ZREMRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByLex
                                        [ZREVRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRangeByLex
                                        [HSCAN] => Predis\Command\HashScan
                                        [PUBSUB] => Predis\Command\PubSubPubsub
                                        [PFADD] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogAdd
                                        [PFCOUNT] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogCount
                                        [PFMERGE] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogMerge
                                        [COMMAND] => Predis\Command\ServerCommand
                                    )

                                [processor:Predis\Profile\RedisProfile:private] => 
                            )

                    )

                [handlers:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [cluster] => Predis\Configuration\ClusterOption
                        [connections] => Predis\Configuration\ConnectionFactoryOption
                        [exceptions] => Predis\Configuration\ExceptionsOption
                        [prefix] => Predis\Configuration\PrefixOption
                        [profile] => Predis\Configuration\ProfileOption
                        [replication] => Predis\Configuration\ReplicationOption
                    )

            )

        [profile:Predis\Client:private] => Predis\Profile\RedisVersion300 Object
            (
                [commands:Predis\Profile\RedisProfile:private] => Array
                    (
                        [EXISTS] => Predis\Command\KeyExists
                        [DEL] => Predis\Command\KeyDelete
                        [TYPE] => Predis\Command\KeyType
                        [KEYS] => Predis\Command\KeyKeys
                        [RANDOMKEY] => Predis\Command\KeyRandom
                        [RENAME] => Predis\Command\KeyRename
                        [RENAMENX] => Predis\Command\KeyRenamePreserve
                        [EXPIRE] => Predis\Command\KeyExpire
                        [EXPIREAT] => Predis\Command\KeyExpireAt
                        [TTL] => Predis\Command\KeyTimeToLive
                        [MOVE] => Predis\Command\KeyMove
                        [SORT] => Predis\Command\KeySort
                        [DUMP] => Predis\Command\KeyDump
                        [RESTORE] => Predis\Command\KeyRestore
                        [SET] => Predis\Command\StringSet
                        [SETNX] => Predis\Command\StringSetPreserve
                        [MSET] => Predis\Command\StringSetMultiple
                        [MSETNX] => Predis\Command\StringSetMultiplePreserve
                        [GET] => Predis\Command\StringGet
                        [MGET] => Predis\Command\StringGetMultiple
                        [GETSET] => Predis\Command\StringGetSet
                        [INCR] => Predis\Command\StringIncrement
                        [INCRBY] => Predis\Command\StringIncrementBy
                        [DECR] => Predis\Command\StringDecrement
                        [DECRBY] => Predis\Command\StringDecrementBy
                        [RPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPushTail
                        [LPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPushHead
                        [LLEN] => Predis\Command\ListLength
                        [LRANGE] => Predis\Command\ListRange
                        [LTRIM] => Predis\Command\ListTrim
                        [LINDEX] => Predis\Command\ListIndex
                        [LSET] => Predis\Command\ListSet
                        [LREM] => Predis\Command\ListRemove
                        [LPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopFirst
                        [RPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopLast
                        [RPOPLPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastPushHead
                        [SADD] => Predis\Command\SetAdd
                        [SREM] => Predis\Command\SetRemove
                        [SPOP] => Predis\Command\SetPop
                        [SMOVE] => Predis\Command\SetMove
                        [SCARD] => Predis\Command\SetCardinality
                        [SISMEMBER] => Predis\Command\SetIsMember
                        [SINTER] => Predis\Command\SetIntersection
                        [SINTERSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetIntersectionStore
                        [SUNION] => Predis\Command\SetUnion
                        [SUNIONSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetUnionStore
                        [SDIFF] => Predis\Command\SetDifference
                        [SDIFFSTORE] => Predis\Command\SetDifferenceStore
                        [SMEMBERS] => Predis\Command\SetMembers
                        [SRANDMEMBER] => Predis\Command\SetRandomMember
                        [ZADD] => Predis\Command\ZSetAdd
                        [ZINCRBY] => Predis\Command\ZSetIncrementBy
                        [ZREM] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemove
                        [ZRANGE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRange
                        [ZREVRANGE] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRange
                        [ZRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRangeByScore
                        [ZCARD] => Predis\Command\ZSetCardinality
                        [ZSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetScore
                        [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByScore
                        [PING] => Predis\Command\ConnectionPing
                        [AUTH] => Predis\Command\ConnectionAuth
                        [SELECT] => Predis\Command\ConnectionSelect
                        [ECHO] => Predis\Command\ConnectionEcho
                        [QUIT] => Predis\Command\ConnectionQuit
                        [INFO] => Predis\Command\ServerInfoV26x
                        [SLAVEOF] => Predis\Command\ServerSlaveOf
                        [MONITOR] => Predis\Command\ServerMonitor
                        [DBSIZE] => Predis\Command\ServerDatabaseSize
                        [FLUSHDB] => Predis\Command\ServerFlushDatabase
                        [FLUSHALL] => Predis\Command\ServerFlushAll
                        [SAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerSave
                        [BGSAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerBackgroundSave
                        [LASTSAVE] => Predis\Command\ServerLastSave
                        [SHUTDOWN] => Predis\Command\ServerShutdown
                        [BGREWRITEAOF] => Predis\Command\ServerBackgroundRewriteAOF
                        [SETEX] => Predis\Command\StringSetExpire
                        [APPEND] => Predis\Command\StringAppend
                        [SUBSTR] => Predis\Command\StringSubstr
                        [BLPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopFirstBlocking
                        [BRPOP] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastBlocking
                        [ZUNIONSTORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetUnionStore
                        [ZINTERSTORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetIntersectionStore
                        [ZCOUNT] => Predis\Command\ZSetCount
                        [ZRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetRank
                        [ZREVRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRank
                        [ZREMRANGEBYRANK] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByRank
                        [HSET] => Predis\Command\HashSet
                        [HSETNX] => Predis\Command\HashSetPreserve
                        [HMSET] => Predis\Command\HashSetMultiple
                        [HINCRBY] => Predis\Command\HashIncrementBy
                        [HGET] => Predis\Command\HashGet
                        [HMGET] => Predis\Command\HashGetMultiple
                        [HDEL] => Predis\Command\HashDelete
                        [HEXISTS] => Predis\Command\HashExists
                        [HLEN] => Predis\Command\HashLength
                        [HKEYS] => Predis\Command\HashKeys
                        [HVALS] => Predis\Command\HashValues
                        [HGETALL] => Predis\Command\HashGetAll
                        [MULTI] => Predis\Command\TransactionMulti
                        [EXEC] => Predis\Command\TransactionExec
                        [DISCARD] => Predis\Command\TransactionDiscard
                        [SUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubSubscribe
                        [UNSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubUnsubscribe
                        [PSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubSubscribeByPattern
                        [PUNSUBSCRIBE] => Predis\Command\PubSubUnsubscribeByPattern
                        [PUBLISH] => Predis\Command\PubSubPublish
                        [CONFIG] => Predis\Command\ServerConfig
                        [PERSIST] => Predis\Command\KeyPersist
                        [STRLEN] => Predis\Command\StringStrlen
                        [SETRANGE] => Predis\Command\StringSetRange
                        [GETRANGE] => Predis\Command\StringGetRange
                        [SETBIT] => Predis\Command\StringSetBit
                        [GETBIT] => Predis\Command\StringGetBit
                        [RPUSHX] => Predis\Command\ListPushTailX
                        [LPUSHX] => Predis\Command\ListPushHeadX
                        [LINSERT] => Predis\Command\ListInsert
                        [BRPOPLPUSH] => Predis\Command\ListPopLastPushHeadBlocking
                        [ZREVRANGEBYSCORE] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRangeByScore
                        [WATCH] => Predis\Command\TransactionWatch
                        [UNWATCH] => Predis\Command\TransactionUnwatch
                        [OBJECT] => Predis\Command\ServerObject
                        [SLOWLOG] => Predis\Command\ServerSlowlog
                        [CLIENT] => Predis\Command\ServerClient
                        [PTTL] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseTimeToLive
                        [PEXPIRE] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseExpire
                        [PEXPIREAT] => Predis\Command\KeyPreciseExpireAt
                        [MIGRATE] => Predis\Command\KeyMigrate
                        [PSETEX] => Predis\Command\StringPreciseSetExpire
                        [INCRBYFLOAT] => Predis\Command\StringIncrementByFloat
                        [BITOP] => Predis\Command\StringBitOp
                        [BITCOUNT] => Predis\Command\StringBitCount
                        [HINCRBYFLOAT] => Predis\Command\HashIncrementByFloat
                        [EVAL] => Predis\Command\ServerEval
                        [EVALSHA] => Predis\Command\ServerEvalSHA
                        [SCRIPT] => Predis\Command\ServerScript
                        [TIME] => Predis\Command\ServerTime
                        [SENTINEL] => Predis\Command\ServerSentinel
                        [SCAN] => Predis\Command\KeyScan
                        [BITPOS] => Predis\Command\StringBitPos
                        [SSCAN] => Predis\Command\SetScan
                        [ZSCAN] => Predis\Command\ZSetScan
                        [ZLEXCOUNT] => Predis\Command\ZSetLexCount
                        [ZRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetRangeByLex
                        [ZREMRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetRemoveRangeByLex
                        [ZREVRANGEBYLEX] => Predis\Command\ZSetReverseRangeByLex
                        [HSCAN] => Predis\Command\HashScan
                        [PUBSUB] => Predis\Command\PubSubPubsub
                        [PFADD] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogAdd
                        [PFCOUNT] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogCount
                        [PFMERGE] => Predis\Command\HyperLogLogMerge
                        [COMMAND] => Predis\Command\ServerCommand
                    )

                [processor:Predis\Profile\RedisProfile:private] => 
            )

    )

[match:protected] => users:anne.castrillon@gmail.com*
[count:protected] => 
[valid:protected] => 1
[fetchmore:protected] => 1
[elements:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[cursor:protected] => 0
[position:protected] => -1
[current:protected] =>
```

)

Comment: Oh i misunderstand that last part of the print_r ... my bad, i'll erase my answer.

Comment: can you paste what the print out looks like?

Comment: sure. it just prints out the iterator object instead of an array

Comment: I think you should be using:  foreach (new Iterator\HashKey($client, 'predis:hash') as $field => $value) {
    echo " - $field => $value", PHP_EOL;
}
Hashkey gives you the field => value that you are expecting.